# Speedup MySQL INSERT operation with .executemany()

Tags: python, mysql, performance, cursor, oursql

How can I use `executemany` here to speed up the process.

```
with dest_conn.cursor() as dcur:
    while True:
        rows = scur.fetchmany(size=25)
        if rows:
            place_holders = "(%s)" % ','.join("?"*len(rows[0]))
            place_holders_list = ', '.join([place_holders] * len(rows))
            insert_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `%s` VALUES %s" % (tname, place_holders_list)
            dcur.execute(insert_query, (val for row in rows for val in row))

        else:
            log("No more rows found to insert")
            break
```

Here `dcur` destination cursor where to copy data and `scur` is source cursor where I am fetching data from

Even I am inserting 25 rows at once (I found this number is optimal for my db) I am creating a prepared statement and executing them. The manual of `oursql` says `executemany` is faster. It can send all the values in batch. How can I use it here instead of `execute`?

Answer (score 2):

There are few things you can change to your code. First, you really should create the insert_query string only once. It will never change in the loop. Also, it seems like you have some errors, like '?'*nr is not returning a sequence, so I correct these as well.

### Using oursql

```
import oursql

# ...

place_holders = '(' + ','.join(['?'] * len(scur.description)) + ')'
insert_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `%s` VALUES %s" % (tname, place_holders)

with dest_conn.cursor() as dcur:
    while True:
        rows = scur.fetchmany(size=25)
        if not rows:
            log("No more rows found to insert")
            break

        dcur.executemany(insert_query, rows)
```

However, I do not see much optimisation done with the executemany() method. It will always use MySQL Prepared Statements and execute each insert one by one.

MySQL General log entries executing using oursql:

```
..
14 Prepare  SELECT * FROM t1
14 Execute  SELECT * FROM t1
15 Prepare  INSERT INTO `t1copy` VALUES (?)
15 Execute  INSERT INTO `t1copy` VALUES (1)
15 Execute  INSERT INTO `t1copy` VALUES (2)
15 Execute  INSERT INTO `t1copy` VALUES (3)
..
```

### Using MySQL Connector/Python

If you use MySQL Connector/Python (note, I'm the maintainer), you'll see different queries going to the MySQL server. Here's the similar code, but reworked so it runs with mysql.connector:

```
import mysql.connector

# ...

place_holders = ','.join(['%s'] * len(scur.description))
place_holders_list = ', '.join([place_holders] * len(scur.description))
insert_query = "INSERT INTO `{0}` VALUES ({1})".format(tname, place_holders_list)

dcur = dest_conn.cursor()
while True:
    rows = scur.fetchmany(size=25)
    if not rows:
        log("No more rows found to insert")
        break

    dcur.executemany(insert_query, rows)
    dest_conn.commit()
```

MySQL General log entries executing using mysql.connector:

```
..
18 Query    SELECT * FROM t1
19 Query    INSERT INTO `t1copy` VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)
19 Query    COMMIT
```

What is faster will have to be benchmarked. oursql is using the MySQL C library; MySQL Connector/Python is pure Python. The magic to make the optimised insert is thus also pure Python string parsing, so you'll have to check it.

### Conclusion

oursql is not optimising the INSERT statement itself. Instead, `executemany()` is only creating the MySQL Prepared Statement once. So that's good.

Comment: If you look carefully my code you'll see it actually generates multiple row insert statement in `insert_query`. `place_holders_list` does that. And as I am fetching `25` rows the number of rows in `place_holders_list` will vary.